# Micronaut not Failfast

Tags: micronaut

I am trying my hands on Micronaut. One of the things I noticed is that Micronaut doesn't failfast.

For example If I have something like this in my bean

```
@Value("${my.url}")
private String url;
```

And if there is no property defined with key my.url, then

1. With Springboot, the server wouldn't start.
2. With Micronaut server would start. But throws an exception when trying to access that variable.

I would assume it would be better to failfast(as in springboot). So was wondering if this is possible in micronaut as well.

Comment: I've been playing with this today also without finding a good solution. I also tried using `@Property(name = "my.url")` and also created a configuration class with `@ConfigurationProperties` with a `@NotNull String myURL;` declaration. Both did not fail until invoked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `@ConfigurationProperties` for this and make sure it is `@Context` scope since by default Micronaut beans are not created on startup. By making them `@Context` scope the bean will be created when the application starts.

The following:

```java
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@ConfigurationProperties("my")
@Context
class MyConfig {

    private @NotNull String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

Results in

```
08:38:38.568 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [fresh.java.MyConfig] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [fresh.java.MyConfig]

Message: Validation failed for bean definition [fresh.java.MyConfig]
List of constraint violations:[
        url - must not be null
]
```

When the server startups up.

Make Sure you add this dependency

```
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work. I am able to start the server. It is even worse I would say. When I injected above bean in a controller and tried calling an endpoint in that controller, I get Page not found. In the logs, it didnt mention that I need to have url property

Comment: Maybe you post the example somewhere I can take a look, I know the above works because a created an app locally that did exactly that so you are probably doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: i have the sme file like you have here. And I have injected this class in my controller. I have an endpoint in my controller, where i return `myConfig .getUrl()`. thats all

Comment: I can confirm this works for the `@ContextProperties` example I'd written. I just popped in `@Context` and `./gradlew run` blew up. Thanks Graeme!

Comment: @pvpkiran I believe I added `compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"` to my `build.gradle` `dependencies`. Ensure you have the same.

Comment: @JonSampson Thanks for the hint. I did not had this dependency. If I add this dependency, then it works as expected. Server wouldn't start. But isn't that strange. I need to add this dependency explicitly. Do you know why?

Comment: @pvpkiran It's the actual implementation of the validation rules. See here: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#validation

Answer (score 2):

Use [eager initialization](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#eagerInit) to make the application fail at startup if there are configuration errors. Example from the Micronaut docs, for cases where the configuration properties are in dedicated beans annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` or similar:

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.build(args)
            .eagerInitConfiguration(true)  // Add this to fail fast
            .mainClass(Application.class)
            .start();
    }
}
```

However, this won't work for configuration properties in regular beans. You can move the configuration to dedicated configuration beans, or, if that'd be too messy, you can tell Micronaut to eagerly initialize everything, which will increase startup time but will fail fast if beans can't be initialized. Replace `eagerInitConfiguration` with `eagerInitSingletons` in the above example (and see the docs for more details).